# Force IE 7 / 8 to resize select width after items are removed

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, html-select

Is it possible to get IE 7 / 8 to recalculate the width of a select box after options are removed? What I find is the width of the largest option is "remembered", and after that largest option is removed, the width does not reduce like it does in good browsers.

The problem does not happen if you execute code instantly after the element, only when trying to manipulate options after DOM ready. Cloning works but is there a better way?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<select id="select">
    <option value="a">aaa</option>
    <option value="b">bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb bbb</option>
</select>

<script>

    // select box is emptied and resizes
    //$("#select").empty(); 

    // long option is removed and select resizes
    //document.getElementById("select").options.remove(1);  

    $(function(){

        // select does not resize after DOM ready
        $("#select").empty();

        // or with this:    
        //document.getElementById("select").options.remove(1);      

        /* cloning works 
        var $select = $("#select"),
            $clone = $select.clone();
        $clone.empty(); 
        $select.replaceWith($clone);
        */  
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried to retrieve [`currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ms535231%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) of `#select`?

Comment: There's no styling applied, and $("#select")[0].currentStyle.width returns "auto", the default value.

Comment: Hmm... I was hoping `currentStyle` had a correct value. How about `$("#select")[0].style.pixelWidth`? (Not having IE<10 at hands right now).

Comment: $("#select")[0].pixelWidth = undefined.  $.detach(), emptying and adding back to the DOM no good either, still the same width

Comment: $("#select")[0].style.pixelWidth = 0